# In xamarin Forms how to stop the webview youtube video when go back?

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

how to stop the youtube video in web view when going back are OnDisappearing method is called.

I have the following XAML web view:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
       <ActivityIndicator x:Name="Progress" IsEnabled="true" IsVisible="true" IsRunning="true" Color="Blue"/>
       <WebView x:Name="webView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Navigated="Handle_Navigated" Navigating="Handle_Navigating" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and have the following (trimmed) code within my **.cs** file:

```
        string name =   o.Link;
        string youtubeLink = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/";
        string url = string.Concat(youtubeLink,name);
        webView.Source = url;

    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        //   webView.IsEnabled = false;

    }
```

When the page calls `OnDisappearing` method I want to stop the webview youtube video but that is currently not what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to stop rendering the WebView. You can either set the WebView Source to a random page or use this:

### Interface

```
public interface ICustomWebViewRenderer
{
    void Pause();
    void Resume();
}
```

#### `Xamarin.Forms` CustomWebView:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public ICustomWebViewRenderer Renderer;

    public void Pause()
    {
        if (renderer != null) renderer.Pause();
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        if (renderer != null) renderer.Resume();
    }
}
```

#### `Xamarin.Android` CustomWebViewViewRenderer:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer, ICustomWebViewRenderer
{
    Android.Webkit.WebView webView;

    public CustomWebViewRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        webView = Control;
        if (e.OldElement != null)
            (e.OldElement as CustomWebView).Renderer = null;
        if (e.NewElement != null)
            (e.NewElement as CustomWebView).Renderer = this;
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        if (webView != null) webView.OnPause();
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        if (webView != null) webView.OnResume();
    }
}
```

#### Example:

#### `XAML`:

```
<local:CustomWebView x:Name="webView" Source="https://youtube.com" />
```

#### `OnDisappearing` / `OnAppearing`:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    webView.Pause();
    base.OnDisappearing();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    webView.Resume();
}
```

Comment: thnx. but where are the  webkit.webview files that  implement of pause and resume method of webView

Comment: Those are native methods that you call in your customrenderer in your Android Project, see the documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebView.OnPause()/

Comment: when in customRenderer      Android.Webkit.WebView webView     then error is occur the error is the type or name "WebKit" does not exist in the namespace of   my project.andorid (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Nice one, glad I could help